# Three.js - shadows rendering on cube but not on imported json mesh object

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, shadow, mesh

I'm trying to get my racecar to cast a shadow on the floor. The shadows are working from the cube (the cube is casting a shadow), but the racecar (imported json mesh object) is not casting a shadow. How can I get the racecar to cast a shadow? Is this something to do with the json file baking on the materials? Does the code `obj.castShadow = true;` actually need to go on a child of the obj? In which case, which child? What am I doing wrong here?

[Here's the json file](http://deepplanet.com/fiddlejs/9/models/ferrari-f1-race-car.json) and [Here's a link to a demo](http://deepplanet.com/fiddlejs/9/)

Here's the relevant code:

```
    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();  
    loader.load("models/ferrari-f1-race-car.json", function (obj) {
        obj.castShadow = true;
        obj.scale.set(50,50,50);
        obj.position.x = 30;
        obj.rotation.y = Math.PI/1;
        scene.add (obj);
    });

    boxgeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 100);
    boxmaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0x0aeedf
    });
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(boxgeometry, boxmaterial);
    cube.castShadow = true;
    cube.position.x = -80;
    cube.position.y = 50;
    cube.position.z = 0;
    scene.add(cube);

    function createFloor(){ 
        floor = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1000,500), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x8594a2}));
        floor.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
        floor.position.y = -0;
        floor.castShadow = false;
        floor.receiveShadow = true;
        scene.add(floor);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting shadows is costly and not well supported on custom objects, there are bugs quite often.

The best solution is to draw a shadow texture on a transparent plane under the car. It can be a problem if you need to rotate you car or your light and need a precise shadow, because the texture won't change with the angle. Up to the author to use tricks (rotate the camera or use much biased shadows). That can still give awesome renderings, check http://helloracer.com/racer-s/ and the simple image used :

[image: shadow texture with bias to replace casted shadow]

Even more impressive :

[image]

For this photorealistic demo http://www.littleworkshop.fr/renaultespace/

Comment: Thank you. And btw those are awesome demo links, did you have anything to do with those projects? Amazing!